# Move files to sysdate folders

Tags: bash, file, directory

I want to make a crontab to move the files from a folder to a sysdate folder.
e.g. from source: /uploads to destination: /archive, move the files from /uploads to /archive/20160619 at the end of the day

So far this is the progress (only want to move pdfs) but i dont know the sysdate part:

```
    #!bin/bash/
SOURCE_DIR="/var/www/html/dms/uploads"
TARGET_DIR="/var/www/html/dms/archive"
FILE_EXTENSION="pdf"
for FILE in $(ls -1 ${SOURCE_DIR} | grep ".${FILE_EXTENSION}"); do
  mv ${SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE} ${TARGET_DIR}/${FILE}"
done
```

Comment: Add to your script `TIMESTAMP=$( date "+%Y%m%d")` and use it

Answer (score 3):

Using the same logic:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="/var/www/html/dms/uploads"
TARGET_DIR="/var/www/html/dms/archive"
FILE_EXTENSION="pdf"
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p $TARGET_DIR/$DATE

mv $SOURCE_DIR/*.$FILE_EXTENSION $TARGET_DIR/$DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can add today's date as a directory name, and create the directory if it doesn't exist yet.

```
mkdir -p "${TARGET_DIR}/`date --utc --rfc-3339=date`/"
mv ${SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE} "${TARGET_DIR}/`date --utc --rfc-3339=date`/${FILE}"
```

Comment: `ls  output` should never be parsed. Bad Idea.

Comment: @sjsam not sure what you mean, please explain.

Comment: `$(ls -1 ${SOURCE_DIR} | grep ".${FILE_EXTENSION}")` will give you inconsistent results when dealing with non-standard file names

Comment: That wasn't even part of my answer. Sure, using `find` would be better, but that's a different topic.

Comment: `That wasn't even part of my answer.` Then, from where did `${FILE}` appear in your code? I thought you were writing the part that comes inside OP's original `for` loop..

Comment: SO answers should focus on answering the question, not on debugging or commenting on other parts of the code. That's what I did. You may want to add your comment to the original question.

Comment: Oh really ? In that case, your solution is  guaranteed to fail very frequently.. As @sjsam said in this  [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) , never parse the output of `ls` command.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below script

```
#/bin/bash
mover()
{
  dirname="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
  if [ -d /var/www/html/dms/archive/"$dirname" ]
    then
  mv "$1" "/var/www/html/dms/archive/$dirname"
  else
    mkdir "/var/www/html/dms/archive/$dirname"
  mv "$1"  "/var/www/html/dms/archive/$dirname" 2>/dev/null
  # I'm Suppressing the error, but you be careful about this
  fi
}

export -f mover

# Find the files using thr find command and move them using the mover function
find /var/www/html/dms/uploads -maxdepth 0 -type f -name "*.pdf" -print0 -exec bash -c 'mover "$0"' {} \;
```

---

**Note :** You should not parse ls output, check [[ this ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) wiki post.

Comment: Why should you do all these things when yaron's answer is a simple alternative?